# The issue of Link API in iText7

Tags: java, itext7

When I generate a pdf document with Link API, there have some strange things. A rectangle always outside the link text. It looks like the cell rectangle, but I didn't set any cell in the document.
[image]

My code is like this:

```
try (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(file));
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);) {
        PdfAction pdfAction = PdfAction.createURI("https://kb.itextpdf.com/home");
        Link link = new Link("https://kb.itextpdf.com/home", pdfAction);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.add(link);
        document.add(paragraph);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it like this:

```
PdfLinkAnnotation linkAnnotation = link.getLinkAnnotation();
linkAnnotation.setBorder(new PdfAnnotationBorder(0, 0, 0));
```